# jQuery AJAX with PHP returning via JSON (Login form)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I don't know what I do wrong..

I have 2 files:
login.php
index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#btnLogin').bind('click', loginToWebsite);
});
function loginToWebsite(){
     $.ajax({  
     url: "login.php",
      type: "POST",  
      data: "username=" + $("#username").val()+"&password=" + $("#password").val(),
    datatype:"json",
      success: function(status)
      {  
        if(status.success == false) 
        {  
            $("#loginform").effect("shake", {times:2}, 100); 
            $("#login_message")  
                .attr('class', 'ui-state-error')  
                .html('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Your details were incorrect.<br />');  
        } 
        else { 
                 $("#login_message")  
                .attr('class', 'ui-state-highlight')  
                .html('<strong>PERFECT</strong>: You may proceed. Good times.<br />');  
            }  
      }  
    });  
} 
</script>
```

login.php gile looks this way:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['password']))
{
    if (login ($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        $data = array("success" => true);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else {
        $data = array("success" => false);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}?>
```

But i get undefined back from login.php (via json)

If I try to alert(status.success) it prints undefined

And I can see i the header that the username and password are getting send to the login.php page.

The PHP function
login() is implemented elsewhere (and returns true or false)

Comment: Is it possible that status.success is being evaluated as a string and not as a boolean?

Comment: Uhm - I have tried to just troubleshoot it, and just to alert the output from login.php - and that still says undefined.

I have also tried to put it like:

$data = array("success" => "something");

and it's still undefined :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the value pass to javascript through variable "status" is a string. So you have to convert the string to json object. To convert string to json object use following script. Use the latest jquery library because older one using different functions to convert string to json.

```
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(status);
    alert(obj.success);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have something bad in your php script output, and it cannot be parsed as json.

1. Try to use some debugging web proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/ for example, there is a free demo)
2. Add console trace to see the data

   success: function(status)
   {
        console.log(status);
        // ... function body
   }

Comment: Thanks deaDrunk :)

So what you say - is that the code is correct - something else is going fishy..

I'll check your link - but first tomorrow (this took me 4 hours to 'try to fix')

Answer (score 0):

Your code in php file is incorrect

```
    if login = false 
{
$data['success'] = false;
echo json_encode($data);
}
else {
$data['success'] = true;
echo json_encode($data);
}
```